# If checkbox default checked, setInterval and do something, if unchecked then clearInterval

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to do a javascript code.
If a checkbox is checked by default, then I have to run a timer with `setInterval`, after if it is unchecked, stop the timer, and after if it's checked again, set the timer again. Hope this is clear.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="autoupdate" checked />

<script>
    window.time = 0; //global declaration
    function autorefresh() {
        var isChecked = document.getElementById("autoupdate").checked;
        if (isChecked == true) {
            time = setInterval(function () {
               alert('hello');
            }, 5000);
        } else if (isChecked == false) {
            clearInterval(time);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So, what's going wrong? Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call autoRefresh once

```
document.getElementById('autoupdate').addEventListener('click', autorefresh);
```

Fiddle:

[**Live Action**](http://jsfiddle.net/8c3GJ/)

Comment: this does the trick for the click event, but let's say i want the alert('hello') to run when the document gets loaded if the checkbox is checked by default like you see the html input code. how do i do that?

Comment: Already we have called autorefresh() function under document.ready so when document gets loaded autorefresh() function automatically called so you are getting alert message every 5 secs after page load. I think Nothing Problem Here.

Comment: Sorry I have missed the autorefresh(); function :D My bad. The code works like charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can just listen to the `click` event.

```
document.getElementById('autoupdate').addEventListener('click', autorefresh);
```

Then you must also call `autorefresh` once the DOM loads to account for the initial state.

Comment: yes thats true, Neophyte had it in the fiddle code, but I have missed it, now it's ok! :)

Comment: @user3767159 Glad I could help. By the way, you should usually select the answer that was given first when two answers are identical. I posted this one 2 minutes before the other.

Comment: Neophyte's first answer was good, he had in his code the autorefresh() function. Only my mistake that I did not check his Fiddle link. So this is why I have selected his answer as first good answer. But I'm glad that you wanted to help, thanks!